# Groovy test files being reported as source files

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using the SonarQube Gradle plugin to send the metrics to Sonar with this configuration in build.gradle:

```
sonarqube {
  properties {
    property 'sonar.host.url', 'http://localhost:9000'
  }
}
```

When I enable the Groovy plugin on the server, Groovy test classes are listed as source files on the server. The project has Java and Groovy files. When the Groovy plugin is disabled, no test classes are reported as source files. When I re-enable the Groovy plugin, all of the Groovy source files AND Groovy test files are reported as source files in Sonar.

Server plugins used:

Java
Groovy

Any idea what would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

The [SonarQube Scanner for Gradle](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-gradle) itself is a Java + Groovy project and it works fine. Could you please create a small reproducer and share it on SonarQube user group? We can update this answer when we have more info.